# Bundling and minification in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 bundling,what is the difference between

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle(.......)...);
```

vs.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle(.......)...);
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(.......)...);
```

From my personal experience it seems that when you use `new Bundle()` it does not try to minify the files inluded anymore.

Is this true? Does anyone have an article that explains this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.

Bundle class serves as a base class, which contains no transformations for a list of file references that are bundled together.

Trasnformations are represented by classes that implement IBundleTransform interface)

You can take a look at msdn or take a look how classes are implemented using dotPeek or similar.

Regards,
Uros